# Adding zerofill to existing table

Tags: mysql, zerofill

I'm trying to add ZEROFILL to an auto-incremented primary ID field in a MySQL database. Here is the code (auto-generated by MySQL Workbench):

```
ALTER TABLE `database`.`table` CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(11) ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error Code: 1025. Error on rename of './database/#sql-2c8_cb' to './database/table' (errno: 150)
```

It appears that a temp table has been created and when the error occurs when the temp table is renamed with the original table name.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Why add the zerofill attribute? MySQL will manage the ids for you automagically.

Comment: Do you have any foreign key constraints on this column?

Comment: @njk: there are three other tables with foreign keys that reference this table. All are set with ON UPDATE CASCADE.

Comment: If using InnoDB, check the status monitor (SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS) right after you execute the alter. It should tell you if it's because of the FK constraint. You may need to drop the constraints, alter the column and create them again.

Comment: @MikePurcell: Each database entry has an associated data file in the file system. The name of each file is simply the field ID. I occasionally need to find a file manually and it's difficult to find things when files are not listed in numerical order.

Comment: @njk: I'm not getting any output from SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS

Comment: @danielfaraday: Interesting. Never seen zerofill used as an attribute on PK column, not sure it will even work.

Comment: @njk: Ah, nevermind. SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS gives plenty of output - I was just doing it wrong. It looks like it was indeed a foreign key problem. I don't understand why this is a problem, since I've set the foreign keys to update automatically. Oh well - it looks like I'll have to drop the constraints first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using InnoDB, check the status monitor (SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS) right after you execute the alter. It should tell you if it's because of the FK constraint. You may need to drop the constraints, alter the column and create them again.

Comment: Or disable and re-enable?